# $n$-sphere is simply connected

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

It is supposed that I could proof this proposition with basic knowledge about homotopies and the fundamental group but it doesn't ocurred. Help me please.
I checked similar quetions but proofs are relatively more complicated, and it is supposed according to the book that it must be simpler.

[image]

It is of Lee's book Introduction to smooth manifolds, page $614$.

Comment: It is easy to see that you can find a path between any two points $x$ and $y$ on $S^n$. Now suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are distinct paths between $x$ and $y$. You should prove that you can always deform one to another, that is, there exists a continuous map $f: I \times I \to S^n$ so that $f(0,t) = \alpha(t)$ and $f(1,t) = \beta(t)$ and $f(s,0) = x$, and $f(s,1) = y$. What would be the obstruction to the existence of such a map?

Comment: A space is simply connected if and only if it has a trivial fundamental group.

Comment: Try the stereographic projection. But you have to show(know) first that any path in the sphere is homotopic to a path that does not pass a specified point.

Comment: Thanks desiigner. Your idea is simple an fruitful.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, there are two classic proofs of this fact. One requires you to prove that for any $x\in S^n$ any $f:S^1\to S^n$ is homotopic to a map $f:S^1\to S^n\setminus\{x\}$ (so to speak, you need to "wriggle" your map in a continuous fashion to avoid a set point). This only holds when $n\geq 2,$ but in that case you can use that $S^n\setminus\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and since this space is simply connected, the map is null-homotopic.

The second classic proof relies on the Van Kampen Theorem to say that $S^n=(S^n\cap \{(x_j)_{1\leq j\leq n+1}\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}|x_{n+1}\geq 0\})\cup (S^n\cap \{(x_j)_{1\leq j\leq n+1}\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}|x_{n+1}\leq 0\})$ and both of these are simply connected (they are, again, homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) and their intersection is path connected when $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Your first argument can be refined and with some work it yields the cellular approximation theorem, which can actually show that $S^n$ is $(n-1)$-connected.

Comment: True, but the question asked to prove the statement using only basic knowledge of homotopies - in which case I assume that we don't know what a CW-complex is.

Comment: I know, I know, I was just pointing it out for further reference (I wasn't implying you should mention that in your answer, which I had actually +1'd already :) )

Comment: Can you give more details about how I can do the first prove?

Comment: @pmtm Uhm... I guess one way to do it is assume $f$ is not constant and fix some sufficiently small ball $B$ around $x$ and note that the intersection of the image of $f$ with $B$ is composed of a set of curves going from boundary to boundary in $B$. Each such curve is homotopic to a curve running along the boundary since $B$ is contractible. Now, there are only countably many of these curves and thus, we can make a giant homotopy of $f$ that performs each of these smaller homotopies one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch of an elementary proof. We will use the following facts:

$1).$ It suffices to prove that if $f : [0, 1] \to S^n$ is a loop in $S^n$, it is null-homotopic.

$2).\ S^n$ with a point removed, is homoeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

$3).$ So, $S^n$ with a two points removed, is homoeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ with a point removed.

Let $U=S^n\setminus \{(0,\ \cdots, 1)\}$ and $V=S^n\setminus \{(0,\ \cdots, -1)\}.$ It is no loss of generality to suppose that $f$ is a loop whose starting (and ending) point is not $(0,\cdots, 1$),because if it is, then we can repeat the argument below, with $(0,\cdots,-1)$ in place of $(0,\cdots,1).$

Now, $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ form a cover of $[0,1]$, so the Lebesgue number lemma applies to show that there is a partition $0<x_1<\cdots <x_{n-2}<1$ such that $f$ maps $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ into either $U$ or $V$ (or both, but if this is the case, choose one of $U$ or $V$.) Letting $f_i$ denote the restriction of $f$ to $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$, divide $I=\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$ into two sets of indices: the first, $I'$, consists of those $i's$ for which $f_i$ maps into $U$, and the second, $I''$, consists of those $i's$ for which $f_i$ maps into $V$.

If $i\in I'$, then $f_i$ does not pass through $(0,\cdots, 1)$ but if $i\in I''$, consider $V\setminus \{(0,\cdots , 1)\}.$ By $3).,$ this set is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ with a point removed, which is path-conncected. Thus, there are continuous functions $f'_i:[x_i,x_{i+1}]\to V\setminus \{(0,\cdots , 1)\}$ such that $f_i(x_i)=f'_i(x_i)$ and $f_i(x_{i+1})=f'_i(x_{i+1}).$ Now $2).$ implies that $f_i\sim f'_i$ via some homotopy $H_i:[x_i,x_{i+1}]\times I\to V.$ Composing with the inclusion map, and still calling the new homotopy $H_i$ we get $H_i:[x_i,x_{i+1}]\times I\to S^n.$

It follows that $g=f_i\cup f'_i:[0,1]\to S^n$ is a continuous loop that misses $(0,\cdots, 1)$ and satisfies $g(0)=f(0)$ and $g(1)=f(1).$ Then,

$H(s,t)=\begin{cases}
f_i(s)\quad s\in [x_i,x_{i+1}];\ i\in I'\\
H_i(s,t)\quad s\in [x_i,x_{i+1}];\ i\in I''
\end{cases}$

is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ and $g$ misses $(0,\cdots, 1)$; that is, $g$ maps into $U$. Now $2).$ implies that $g$ is null-homotopic, and so, so is $f$.

Comment: You argue using the path-connectedness that we can find another continuous function with the same start and end point, but what if $f_i(x_i)$ is in fact the north pole? Wouldn't that break the argument because we also demand that the image lies in $V\setminus\{(0, \cdots, 1)\}$?