# prove that $f:S^1\rightarrow S^2$ continuous is nulhomotopic

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I nedd to prove that any continuous $f:S^1\rightarrow S^2$ is nulhomotopic.
I've tried 2 different ways and both of them have a little problem.
I hope you can help me solve that, or give me anther idea for a solution.

- first Idea
  let $x_0\in S^2$ some point.
  use the fact that $S^2$ is path connected so for any $x\in S^2$ there exist a path $h_x$ from x to $x_0$.
  now define $F:S^1\times I\rightarrow S^2$ ,
  $F(x,t)=
  \begin{cases}
  f(x),  & 0\le 0\le 0.5 \\
  h_{f(x)}, & 0.5\le 0\le 1
  \end{cases}
  $
  If F is continuous do it's homotopy and we done. But I'm not sure it's actually continuous and how to prove it.
- Second Idea
  define $\varphi :I\rightarrow S^1$ by $\varphi (s)=(cos(2\pi s),sin(s\pi s))$.
  we get that
  $F\circ \varphi$ begin and start at the same point in $S^2$. we know thath $S^2$ is simply connected so we know that $F\circ \varphi$ is nulhomotopic.
  and $Im(f)=Im(F\circ \varphi)$, so if we look at f as $f:\varphi (I)=S^1\rightarrow S^2$  we should get the wanted homotopy. but I'm not sure if it works and correct.

Will appreciate any help

Comment: Are you assuming that $S^2$ is simply connected? That's pretty much the same as what you want to prove?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to use stereographic projection and the fact that the plane is simply-connected. Be sure that you project from a point which does not intersect the image of the loop - importantly, you should first show that every loop is homotopic to a loop which misses at least one point in the sphere (this needs to be considered because of the existence of space-filling curves).

Comment: Try [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3807715/a-continuous-map-f-s1-to-s2-is-homotopic-to-a-point) for some hints.

Comment: This is a special case of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305039/n-sphere-is-simply-connected).

Comment: @AnginaSeng
why assuming that $S^2$ is simply connected is enough?
how excatly can I use it?

Comment: @PawełCzyż why assuming that S2 is simply connected is enough? how excatly can I use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$n$-sphere is simply connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305039/n-sphere-is-simply-connected)

Comment: @MoisheKohan
No, I still don't understand how assuming that S2 is simply connected is enough because f is not a path $[0,1]\rightarrow S^2$, it's $S^1\rightarrow  S^2$

Comment: @Nitz Paths whose endpoints coincide $[0,1]\to S^2$ are the same as maps $S^1\to S^2$, and path homotopies correspond to basepoint preserving homotopies.

Comment: @jgon why is this the same?  $[0,1]→S^2$  $S^1→S^2$, this is exactly the part I don't understand
if $S^1$ and [0,1] were homeomorphic I could  understand, but It's not so how can I just switch?

Comment: @Nitz Because $S^1$ is (homeomorphic to) the interval with endpoints identified. The claim then follows from the universal property of the quotient.